# Bash awk print matched delimiter

Tags: awk

Is there a way to print the currently matched delimiter with awk?

For example:

```
awk -F '["RESTART" | "FAILURE" | "WARNING" | [:blank:]]{2}' 'FNR > 4 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i;}' file
```

Example Input

```
XX      XXXX   RESTART 6666  XX X
XXXX    XXXX   WARNING 8888  YYY YYY
XXX     XXXX   INFORM  7777  XXXX XX
```

Example Output (must)

```
XX
XXXX
RESTART
6666
XX X
XXXX
XXXX
WARNING
8888
YYY YYY
XXX
XXXX
INFORM
7777
XXXX XX
```

Example Output (now)

```
XX
XXXX
6666
XX X
XXXX
XXXX
8888
YYY YYY
XXX
XXXX
INFORM
7777
XXXX XX
```

I use more than 2 white spaces as column delimiter, but there are some cases (`RESTART 6666`) or (`WARNING 8888`) where two columns are not separated by two whitespaces, that is why I have to use the content (`RESTART`, `WARNING`) as delimiter, but if I use the content as delimiter, it doesn't get displayed, so I want to display/print the used delimiter (in case it is content and not whitespaces)

The main problem is to differentiate between one white space used as column separator and one white space used as word separator in one column. I cannot affect the file I have to deal with.

Comment: Can you post the question with an actual de-limiter and with actual file contents? This information is not sufficient

Comment: Added some more tips

Comment: it looks confusing. Post the input fragment and desired result

Comment: Can your data `xxx`  have single space in between ?

Comment: @batMan yes, see the example output

Comment: I mean .. can `xxx` represent data like strings with single space for eg `"Two words"`

Comment: @batMan yes, that is the main problem

Comment: In your awk, you've mentioned FAILURE but it isn't in your input file. also you've INFORM in your input which isn't in your awk command ? Do you have 4 exceptions (RESTART,WARNING,INFORM,FAILURE) ?

Comment: @batMan the only exceptions are listed as `awk delimiter`: "RESTART", "FAILURE", "WARNING" any other content (inclusive INFORM) works as expected

Comment: I don't understand the question or what you're trying to do. You say `I use more than 2 white spaces as column delimiter` which is fine but then you say `but there are some cases.. where two columns are not separated by two whitespaces` so which is it - are your columns separated by 2 or more white spaces or are they separated by any amount of white space? Is the Example Output what you're trying to get or what you currently get and don't want? Is `RESTART 6666` one field or 2? Is that the problem - you want it treated as 1 field but your script is treating it as 2? I'm lost...

Comment: @EdMorton Example input is my real input. I have to split this log file (which contains of columns) into array. So I saw, that the columns (in most cases) are delimited by more than two white spaces. But in the log file you find two columns which are separated by only one white space. So when I use two spaces as delimiter, the `RESTART 6666` doesn't get split properly. The Example output is the output as it should be. I added desired output and now output.

Comment: So how can you (or a tool) determine that `RESTART 6666` is 2 fields while `XX X` is one field?

Comment: @EdMorton that is the problem, I use the `RESTART` as delimiter, and thought I can than add it to the `print`. How can I otherwise split such a bullshit log file into array elements each representing one column value?

Comment: It actually looks to me like you have fixed with fields (i.e. each field starts at a specific character position) rather than string-separated fields (i.e. each field is separated from it's neighbors by 2 or more blank chars or some other string) - could that be true?

Comment: @EdMorton character position is not important for me, I wanted to omit reading the value from one specific char position because it is very dirty

Comment: That's much less dirty than testing for a bunch of specific strings in your input, especially if your data **IS** fixed width fields which is a very common format (common enough that GNU awk has a specific FIELDWIDTHS variable for handling it) and the sample you posted looks very much like you have.

Comment: @EdMorton do you have a quick example for that? I am actually java developer and I am pissed by bash scripting atm :)

Comment: Your problem is you're on Solaris whose default toolset dates back to the 1970s and in some cases is riddled with bugs (e.g. the default awk that's in /bin is "old, broken awk" which should never be used by anyone!). The tools in /usr/xpg4/bin solve some of those issues (and xpg6). Yes, I'll post a fixed width fields solution that'll work with any modern awk. One minute...

Comment: @EdMorton I use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`

Comment: Good. I've posted an answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46157672/1745001. If your data turns out to NOT be fixed width fields then please updated your sample input/output to show a more truly representative example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk:**

```
awk '{gsub(/  +|\t/,"\n")} {print}' file | awk '/RESTART|WARNING|FAILURE/{gsub(/ /,"\n")}  {print}'
```

`gsub(/  +|\t/,"\n")`: to replace "2 or more spaces OR \t" with newline `\n`.
This converts our file into multiple lines wherein each line can consist of multiple words separated by single space only.

`/RESTART|WARNING|FAILURE/{gsub(/ /,"\n")` : if line contains one of these 3 words then replace space  with `\n`

You can also use **sed** :

```
sed "s/\s\s\+/\n/g; s/\(RESTART\|WARNING\|FAILURE\) /\1\n/g"  file
```

for older sed-version (mostly in MAC): + mayn't be supported so modify it for *

```
sed "s/\s\s\s*/\n/g; s/\(RESTART\|WARNING\|FAILURE\) /\1\n/g"  file
```

`s/\s\s\+/\n/g` : replaces 2 or more than spaces to single `\n`
`s/\(RESTART\|WARNING\|FAILURE\) /\1\n/g` : replaces space with `\n` after your 
three exceptions

Input:

```
line one      hello hello   RESTART 6666  XX X
line two    hello hello   WARNING 8888  YYY YYY
line three  hello hello      INFORM  7777  XXXX XX
```

Output:

```
line one
hello hello
RESTART
6666
XX X
line two
hello hello
WARNING
8888
YYY YYY
line three
hello hello
INFORM
7777
XXXX XX
```

Comment: Are you sure it gives that output? I get the complete file not splitted at all printed in the console

Comment: you maybe using older sed version which isn't supporting `+` (are u on mac ? ) .. try my updated answer...

Comment: solaris 5.8 with bash 2.

Comment: That's funny I was about to comment something like "If you think sed on MACs is old, wait til you see Solaris" :-). Yes, the default sed on Solaris won't support `\s` for spaces nor `\|` or any other ERE metacharacters. idk if there's a newer sed in /usr/xpg4/bin but take a look...

Comment: @Sirion: Can you try this `awk '{gsub("(   *)|\t","\n")} {print}' file | awk '/RESTART/ || /WARNING/ || /FAILURE/{gsub(" ","\n")}  {print}'` . I have also accounted in `\t`. If you don't have tabs or don't want tabs to be accounted, you can remove it from gsub.  Let me put it into answer as some spaces are getting truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fixed width fields approach that will work with any awk (except, of course, old broken awk /bin/awk on Solaris where you should use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    # identify the fields:
    nf = 0
    f[++nf] = substr($0,1,8)
    f[++nf] = substr($0,9,7)
    f[++nf] = substr($0,16,8)
    f[++nf] = substr($0,24,6)
    f[++nf] = substr($0,30)

    # remove leading/trailing white space from each field:
    for (i in f) {
        sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",f[i])
        sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",f[i])
    }

    # print the fields:
    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        print NR, i, "<" f[i] ">"
    }
    print "---"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 1 <XX>
1 2 <XXXX>
1 3 <RESTART>
1 4 <6666>
1 5 <XX X>
---
2 1 <XXXX>
2 2 <XXXX>
2 3 <WARNING>
2 4 <8888>
2 5 <YYY YYY>
---
3 1 <XXX>
3 2 <XXXX>
3 3 <INFORM>
3 4 <7777>
3 5 <XXXX XX>
---
```

If you used `nawk` on Solaris then you'd have to replace `[[:space:]]` with `[ \t]` since it predates POSIX character classes but just don't use nawk, use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead.

It can be modified to use a loop instead of 5 explicit substr() calls if this approach works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use GNU awk's `split` with *seps*. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html tells:

> split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])
>
> seps is a gawk extension, with seps[i] being the separator string between array[i] and array[i+1].